# The solution of $AX=B$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

> $A=\begin{bmatrix}8&3\\2&6\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}3\\-1\end{bmatrix}$
>
> Find the solution of the system of linear equations $AX=B$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Note that $\det A=42$.

**Now** it is written in *Artin's Algebra* that "The system has no solution in $\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{F}_3$. It happens to have solutions in $\mathbb{F}_7$, though $\det A=0$ in that field."

I understood why the system has no solution in $\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{F}_3$, but **why** there happens to be solution in $\mathbb{F}_7$?

***Added***:

Thanks to @quid, I understood it clearly.

So in general if $\det A=p^{k_1}_1\cdot p^{k_2}_2\cdots p^{k_n}_n$, then is there any general rule for which $p_i$ we have no solution and for which $p_i$ we have multiple solution.

Comment: Just solve the system to check that it has solutions. I mean, I assume it was essentially the same way you saw that it did not have solutions in those other cases.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I can solve for any $p\neq 2,3,7$ (process is given in the book...), but how to do for $p=7$?

Comment: Does the book really give a procedure to solve that only works for invertible matrices? The usual methods work in complete generality.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It is done for $p\neq 2,3,7$... so for invertable matrices, yes.

Comment: $Ax = b$ has a solution iff $b \in Im(A)$. If $A$ is a square matrix and $\det(A) \ne 0$ then $Im(A)$ is the whole space.

Comment: What is done for those primes?

Comment: I actually quoted that here ... nothing more written there! @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: But I asked you about solving linear equations in general. And you said you could see that there was no solutions for $p=2$ and $p=3$. So how did you see this?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft at first I thought that since $3\mid 42$ and $2\mid 42$. So  no solution for that... but for $p=7$ this logic did not work here.

Comment: This is, as pointed out in the answer, completely analogous to the case over the reals with determinant $0$. There is essentially no difference.

Comment: yes, I understood it clearly now @TobiasKildetoft . So in general if $\det A=p^{k_1}_1\cdot p^{k_2}_2\cdots p^{k_n}_n$, then is there any general rule for which $p_i$ we have no solution and for which $p_i$ we have multiple solution, like real case?

Comment: What sort of rule are you referring to in the real case?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft in real case if we have two parallel line having no common point we assure that no solution and if they coincide we say finitely many solution. Is something like that can be said here too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over any field, if the matrix is invertible/has non-zero determinant than there is a unique solution for any vector on the right-hand side.

However, if the matrix in non-invertible/has zero-determinant there are two possibilities for a given right-hand side.

Either there is no solution or there are multiple solutions (that form an affine subspace).

In the case of $2$ and $3$ you land in the former case, in the case of $7$ you land in the latter.

As you ask in a comment how to solve it for $7$, put the extended matrix in echelon form, and substitute. It is the same as you would do for an under-determined system over the reals.

$\begin{bmatrix}8&3\\2&6\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}3\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

reducing modulo seven gives

$\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\2&6\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}3\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

Now subtract twice the first from the second line to get:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Crucially note that the second coordinate of the vector is $0$ as $-1 -2 \times 3 =0$. Now, introduce a parameter for one of the two variables and express the second using the one remaining equation.

To answer the additional question, one cannot decide for which prime there will be a solution based on the determinant of $A$ or even based on $A$ alone. One really has to check for each prime what happens for the given right-hand side. In that sense it is as in the reals, it really depends on the combination of matrix *and* right-hand side.

Yet, if $B$ is the zero-vector, one will always have multiple solutions.

One could say informally, and also make rigorous, that for small primes it is more likely that there are multiple solution but this is rather besides the point and a distraction in this context.

Comment: But how to show for $p=7$, we will have multiple solution?

Comment: Yes. I included some details. It is really the same as you would do over the reals when faced with an underdetermined system.

Comment: Thanks, I understood, so in general if $\det A=p^{k_1}_1\cdot p^{k_2}_2\cdots p^{k_n}_n$, then is there any general rule for which $p_i$ we have no solution and for which $p_i$ we have multiple solution, like real case?

Comment: One cannot decide this based on the determinant of $A$ or even based on $A$ alone. One really has to check for each prime what happens for the given right-hand side. In that sense it is as in the reals, it really depends on the combination of matrix and right-hand side

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer !!!